# Poor review audit sample

Tags: discussion, review-audit

[P(tomorrow is the end of the world) =?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467511/ptomorrow-is-the-end-of-the-world) failed me—the system sees no serious problem with this question. The comments, in my view correctly, suggest otherwise—it is, at best, unclear what is being asked. At worst, the question is too philosophical to be on-topic.

I'm not arguing that the question should be closed, but I think debate on that is sufficiently valid that it shouldn't be an audit question.

Comment: I flagged it as opinion-based; I hope that's correct since the discussions in the answers clearly show largely differing views on the "topic".

Comment: @AlexR It's a mathematical question and it generates a good discussion.  It wasn't closed when it was posted almost a month ago and I don't think it should be closed now.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I love this question and think it generates a terrific discussion on probability.  The question makes you think and gets right to the heart of some of the deep nuances in probability.

The question has 11 upvotes and no downvotes, so many users besides me agree this is a great question for this site.  Presumably, the system picked it *because* it has 11 upvotes and 0 downvotes, and in general I think that's a good reason to pick a question for a review audit.  That is, even if this is a bad question for review (which I don't think it is), I don't think the system has made a mistake in picking it, since the upvotes make it very unlikely to be a bad question.

Comment: Attracting upvotes sometimes means that this question perhaps got some attention from outside MSE.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I am *quite* aware of that, but in that case it will attract downvotes too, though less in number.  No downvotes and 11 upvotes is a pretty good sign that the regulars on mathSE like it - if the regulars didn't, one of them would have downvoted.

Comment: A question can be interesting even if it is off-topic or has other problems that would lead to it being closed, without necessarily deserving down-votes.